# List stored in a session wrapper remains with Count 0 although method called to add item into it

Tags: c#, list, session, generics, count

I am a beginner, learning ASP.Net, so apologies in advance if the codes are really messy, I am also still learning the sessions and some of the terms in .Net. Anyway, I am using session to retain values during postback. However, I think I am not coding them properly, I am having difficulty understanding the whole session in a list concept thingy, I understand how session works, but session and generic list is so confusing. Anyway, this is the code.

```
 public class MySessionWrapper
{
    private MySessionWrapper()
    {

    }
    private static List<DateTime> _Week_1;
    public static List<DateTime> A_Week_1 
    {
        get
        {
            _Week_1 = (List<DateTime>) HttpContext.Current.Session["A_Week_1"];
            if(_Week_1 == null)
            {
                _Week_1 = new List<DateTime>();
            }
            return (List<DateTime>)_Week_1;
        }
    }

    public static void AddWeek1(DateTime add_date)
    {

        A_Week_1.Add(add_date);
    }
```

}

```
//and I am calling it from here using something like this 
if (weeknum == 1)
            {
                MySessionWrapper.AddWeek1(date1);
            }
```

The thing is, I noticed that the MySessionWrapper.AddWeek1 method remains as 0 although there are values hitting the weeknum == 1. It goes to the session wrapper class does not add the value at all into the List. I would really need some guidance on understanding session with generic list and could someone point what exactly am I doing wrong here.

Hi guys, I have edited the code again like what Gaurav pointed out, but I am getting stuck again, this time the list has already been initialized but with a certain number of count in it. Maybe I can explain better what I want to do. 
I have a drop down list that contains the months. So, if a user selects February, the program would actually divide the dates within the month into respective weeks, weekofDay being Monday. So for example, in February, it should be

```
Months -- Week Start Date ---- Week End Date
Week1 - 2/1/2019 12:00:00 AM - 2/3/2019 12:00:00 AM
Week2 - 2/4/2019 12:00:00 AM - 2/10/2019 12:00:00 AM
Week3 - 2/11/2019 12:00:00 AM - 2/17/2019 12:00:00 AM
Week4 - 2/18/2019 12:00:00 AM - 2/24/2019 12:00:00 AM
Week5 - 2/25/2019 12:00:00 AM - 2/28/2019 12:00:00 AM
```

So, this now works fine after the page load and I choose February, but again I would like to see for March and the page gets refreshed but the Week Start Dates remains at February ones, the Week End Dates gets updated accordingly.

Is this something to do with the sessions ?

Comment: there is no line of code where you assign your list back to `.Session["A_Week_1"]`

Comment: You need to define setter for your A_Week_1 property.

Comment: I would remove the `private static List<DateTime> _Week_1`. It looks like a recipe for future mistakes.

Comment: @Gaurav No, that's not required at all

Comment: @John - Would just need to clarify, why would I need to remove the private line..and use var instead, I read that "Properties enable a class to expose a public way of getting and setting values, while hiding implementation or verification code. " Not sure if I am learning it the right way, but could you please advice, as I always thought that in a class, we would need to have a private field and then a property that's public to expose it.

Comment: In the general case that's right, but _in this case_ you're using the property to expose a value stored in the session cache, not a field on the object. Essentially your `A_Week_1` property is a _calculated property_. It's not a property to expose a field. Because `_Week_1` is `static`, any thread (any request) can come in and edit this field. So `request2` might come in while `request1` is between assigning `_Week_1` and returning it, thereby returning the wrong value - a value belonging to a different session.

Comment: And, of course, since `_Week_1` isn't an actual backing field for the property, there's the potential that you could try to use it without obtaining a value through `A_Week_1`. Doing so would essentially pick up the last assigned value, no matter which session it belonged to.

Comment: Is your edit the same issue or a new issue?

Comment: The same, but I think this is more about clearing the session once the drop down is selected again as the page gets refreshed but retains the data from the old session.

Comment: I've added a little to my answer. You'll need to somehow reset the value (either by clearing the session cache, the week list, or replacing the list). I've amended my answer slightly. If you need more help than that, I'd recommend creating a new question.

Comment: @John, should be solved now,  I used this Session.Clear() in the first line where after the dropdown event handler. Hopefully this is the right way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend rewriting your method like so:

```
public static List<DateTime> A_Week_1 
{
    get
    {
        var week1 = (List<DateTime>)HttpContext.Current.Session["A_Week_1"];
        if(week1 == null)
        {
            week1 = new List<DateTime>();
            HttpContext.Current.Session["A_Week_1"] = week1;
        }
        return week1;
    }
}
```

I've ditched `private static List<DateTime> _Week_1;` since it's not useful or necessary.

If you need to, you can add a setter method to "reset" the value:

```
public static List<DateTime> A_Week_1 
{
    get
    {
        var week1 = (List<DateTime>)HttpContext.Current.Session["A_Week_1"];
        if(week1 == null)
        {
            week1 = new List<DateTime>();
            HttpContext.Current.Session["A_Week_1"] = week1;
        }
        return week1;
    }
    set
    {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["A_Week_1"] = value;
    }
}
```

Then you can either reset it by setting `A_Week_1 = null` (thereby forcing the getter to create a new list next time you access the getter), or you can manually set it to a new list (e.g. `A_Week_1 = new List<DateTime>();`).

Of course, you could also "reset" by simply clearing the list: `A_Week_1.Clear();`

Comment: @Dr.Snail Is set needed?

Comment: Yes session will not get updated with out set property.

Comment: @Gaurav How do you mean? OP is not setting the property, OP is using members of the referenced object obtained through the property (`List<DateTime>`).

Comment: @Gaurav, initially, I wanted to have set. but then all I wanted was to actually add items into the list and I googled as everything I include the List.Add(date) into the set property accessor, it was not working as expected( maybe I did it the wrong way ), it kept making the list to null instead of keeping it initialized. I googled and some suggested to have a method instead that adds the item into the list, hence the approach.

Comment: @John, having different issues, I have edited my post to make it clearer now. Please help.

Comment: @John, thanks a bundle, I have used Session.Clear() for now, got it sorted out. Will post another question if the session.clear does not work as expected. thank you..